# sudo in .desktop file when launching graphical app

Tags: linux, fedora

Fedora 14

i can run a program with another user with:

(command before): `xhost local:transmission-user`

the command:
`sudo -u transmission-user -- /usr/bin/transmission-gtk &`

from the gnome-terminal.

But:

`echo -e '#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open\n\n[Desktop Entry]\nVersion=1.0\nType=Application\nTerminal=true\nIcon[en_US]=gdu-encrypted-lock\nName[en_US]=transmission-user\nExec=sudo -u transmission-user -- /usr/bin/transmission-gtk &\nName=transmission-user\nIcon=gdu-encrypted-lock' > transmission-user.desktop`
`chmod +x transmission-user.desktop`

it doesn't work, if i put the command in a .desktop file.

Why?

Comment: just to be sure: you made sure you don't need to type a pasword? otherwise you'd want to use something like gksu - or visudo...

Comment: i don't need password because this: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=sZvT7gf5

Answer (score 0):

Replacing

`Exec=sudo -u username -- /usr/bin/xeyes &`

with

`Exec=sudo -u username -- /usr/bin/xeyes`

worked for me. (remove the "&" at the end of the Exec line)

Comment: Its not working in ubuntu 14.04.02 LTS for me..